# How to specify host ip adress of my shiny server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I've been using shiny for about a month now. I have a working app. I want my app to be available to other in my work's network. I made it work within RStudio using the host option. Something like :runApp(host="132.207.xx.xx", port=6215). For it to work, I really need to use the static ip of the pc. Using the localhost option was not working.

I would like to do the same with the shiny server. Is there a way to configure it to do something similar?

thanks for your help

Comment: Shiny Server by default can be accessed throughout your local network.

Comment: It can, but not using the localhost address (127.0.0.1).I need to specify the static ip of the computer. Within RStudio, if I was not specifying the host (i.e. using localhost), I was not able to access the server from another computer on the local network.

Comment: @Bikroy did you find a way to do it because i have the same problem

Comment: @Bikroy were u able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the conf file at /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
add the following inside server{}

listen port ip-address

example:
listen 8000 10.224.11.6;